# Python web scraping array but going to default page first

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I would like to webscrape the individual listings details on this sheriff's sale page. So far, I have managed to gather in an array the list of urls to scrape. However, the trouble I'm having is that when the url's are entered on their own, they default to this page with all of the counties that this website has sheriff's sales for: https://salesweb.civilview.com/. I'm thinking that i need to post the cookies of the site as I sort through the arrays, but any help would be appreciated. I am working in jupyter and python 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import requests
import requests.cookies
import time

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL that I want to get to collect house details from. 
url = "https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=23"
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
type(soup)

# collect the links for all of the houses
records = []
for item in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
    if item.text:
        records.append(item['href'])
print(records)

# add beginning part of house url's because the href does not include the entire url
string = 'https://salesweb.civilview.com'
my_new_list = [string + x for x in records]
print (my_new_list)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': "https://salesweb.civilview.com/"}

# Just want to test if i can collect information from individual house, this is where i get the error
for house in my_new_list:
    session.post(url, cookies = cj, headers = headers)
    houses = requests.get(house)
    soup_pages = BeautifulSoup(houses.content, 'html.parser')

    #print body only

    table = soup_pages.find_all('td')
    print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will traverse each county and stored all information to dictionary `all_data`, then it created dataframe from it and saves it as csv:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pandas as pd

url = 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
urls = [(a.text, 'https://salesweb.civilview.com' + a['href']) for a in soup.select('a')]

all_data = {'County':[], 'Sheriff No': [], 'Status': [], 'Sales Date': [], 'Attorney': [], 'Parcel No': [], 'Plaintiff': [], 'Defendant': [], 'Address': []}
for county, url in urls:
    print('Processing {} URL={}...'.format(county, url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    for tr in soup.select('tr:has(td)'):
        # print( tr.select('td') )
        tds = tr.select('td')
        if len(tds) == 6:
            _, sheriff_no, sales_date, plaintiff, defendant, address = tds
            status = '-'
            attorney = '-'
            parcel_no = '-'
        elif len(tds) == 7:
            _, sheriff_no, status, sales_date, plaintiff, defendant, address = tds
            status = status.get_text(strip=True)
            attorney = '-'
            parcel_no = '-'
        elif len(tds) == 9:
            _, status, sales_date, sheriff_no, attorney, plaintiff, parcel_no, defendant, address = tds
            status = status.get_text(strip=True)
            attorney = attorney.get_text(strip=True)
            parcel_no = '-'

        all_data['County'].append(county)
        all_data['Sheriff No'].append(sheriff_no.get_text(strip=True))
        all_data['Status'].append(status)
        all_data['Sales Date'].append(sales_date.get_text(strip=True))
        all_data['Plaintiff'].append(plaintiff.get_text(strip=True))
        all_data['Attorney'].append(attorney)
        all_data['Parcel No'].append(parcel_no)
        all_data['Defendant'].append(defendant.get_text(strip=True))
        all_data['Address'].append(address.get_text(strip=True))

# all information is stored now in `all_data`, but let's create a dataframe from it:

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Processing Allen County, OH URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=34...
Processing Atlantic County, NJ URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=25...

...

                   County   Sheriff No Status  ...                                          Plaintiff                                          Defendant                                            Address
0     Atlantic County, NJ   F-20000248      -  ...                            Ocean City Home Bank...                            Richard W. Lemmerman...  5348 White Horse Pike Mailing Address: Egg Har...
1     Atlantic County, NJ   F-19001833      -  ...                               Selene Finance LP...                            Darrin M. Lord;Susan...          9 Saint Andrews Drive Northfield NJ 08225
2     Atlantic County, NJ   F-19001941      -  ...                            The Bank of New York...                            Raymond Mooney; Donn...          574 Revere Way Galloway Township NJ 08205
3       Bergen County, NJ   F-18001316      -  ...                                MTGLQ INVESTORS, LP                        JENNIFER A. SKOVRAN, ET AL.              21-06 DALTON PLACE FAIR LAWN NJ 07410
4       Bergen County, NJ   F-18001967      -  ...  U.S. BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION, AS TRUSTEE FOR...                            HENRY CASANOVA, ET ALS.            488 VICTOR STREET SADDLE BROOK NJ 07663
...                   ...          ...    ...  ...                                                ...                                                ...                                                ...
2288     Union County, NJ  CH-19000471      -  ...  US BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION, AS TRUSTEE FOR C...  ROBERT E. HARRIS, ELLEN HARRIS, WELLS FARGO BA...                98 BELMONT AVENUE CRANFORD NJ 07016
2289     Union County, NJ  CH-19001682      -  ...                             WELLS FARGO BANK, N.A.  SONNY CORREA A/K/A SONNY P. CORREA; RUBENIA CO...      813-15 WEST FOURTH STREET PLAINFIELD NJ 07063
2290     Union County, NJ  CH-19002054      -  ...                             WELLS FARGO BANK, N.A.  MANUEL BARREIRA, LAUREN E. BARREIRA, UNITED ST...            524 WILLOW AVENUE ROSELLE PARK NJ 07204
2291     Union County, NJ  CH-19002308      -  ...  U.S. BANK NATIONAL ASSOCIATION, AS TRUSTEE FOR...  LAUREN LEASTON AKA LAUREN S. LEASTON, UNITED S...            418-420 GREEN COURT PLAINFIELD NJ 07060
2292     Union County, NJ  CH-19002582      -  ...  U.S. BANK NA, SUCCESSOR TRUSTEE TO BANK OF AME...  EMILIE JOSEPH; ACB RECEIVABLES; AND NEWARK BET...                        1239 VICTOR AVENUE UNION NJ

[2293 rows x 9 columns]
```

The `data.csv` upon opening in LibreOffice:

[image]

EDIT (To get detailed data of Montgomery County, PA):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url of Montgomery County, PA:
url = 'https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=23'

with requests.session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
    data = []

    for a in soup.select('a:contains("Details")'):
        url = 'https://salesweb.civilview.com' + a['href']
        print('Processing URL={}...'.format(url))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
        t = []
        for tr in soup.table.select('tr'):
            title, value, _ = tr.select('td')
            t.append((title.get_text(strip=True).replace('#&colon', '').replace('&colon', ''), value.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')))
        data.append(dict(t))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Prints:

```
...
Processing URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=877879948...
Processing URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=877879634...
Processing URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=877879962...
Processing URL=https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=877879654...
     Sheriff  Court Case  Sales Date                               Plaintiff  ...         Attorney Phone           Parcel  Law Reporter               Township
0    18002083    18-03910  5/27/2020                     HSBC Bank USA, N.A.  ...           215-790-1010  49-00-00142-00-7                   Plymouth Township
1    17011341    17-24059  5/27/2020                      CitiMortgage, Inc.  ...  215 942-2090 ext 1337  46-00-00005-26-4                 Montgomery Township
2    11008592    11-16634  5/27/2020                        Wells Fargo Bank  ...           215-790-1010  37-00-00742-13-9                   Limerick Township
3    18005541    18-05020  5/27/2020          Souderton Area School District  ...           866-211-9466  34-00-00590-42-9                  Franconia Township
4    19002379    19-03925  5/27/2020          PNC Bank, National Association  ...           614-220-5611  46-00-00666-18-8                 Montgomery Township
..        ...         ...        ...                                     ...  ...                    ...               ...           ...                   ...
351  19000239    19-00174  9/30/2020  J.P. Morgan Mortgage Acquisition Corp.  ...           856-384-1515  31-00-21991-00-1                 Cheltenham Township
352  19010961    19-24540  9/30/2020             Bayview Loan Servicing, LLC  ...           614-220-5611  01-00-03754-00-7                      Ambler Borough
353  19006687    19-16329  9/30/2020      The Bank of New York Mellon, et al  ...           516-699-8902  04-00-00809-10-5                Collegeville Borough
354  19011323    19-25220  9/30/2020                  Wells Fargo Bank, N.A.  ...           614-220-5611  52-00-18466-00-4                Springfield Township
355  19007225    19-18256  9/30/2020                              NewRez LLC  ...           516-699-8902  13-00-00384-00-8                  Norristown Borough

[356 rows x 13 columns]
```

And `data.csv` looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wow that's great @AndrejKesely! Quick question, you know how each of those listings has the details page with additional info like debt amount, attorney phone, parcel # etc. Is there a way to include that level of detail? I'm also just looking at Montgomery County, PA. I should have mentioned that :) Thanks so much!